# Can't work with reusable cells. How to optimize smooth scrolling in tableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, uitableview, optimization

My app has a bunch of horizontal tableViews inside a normal vertical tableView.

Here is a picture to illustrate:

[image]

This results in a quite nice horizontal scrolling, but it's more than I can say for the vertical scrolling. The vertical scroll is pretty laggy. 
I know that each tableView will have its own reusable cells and therefore can't be shared across other tableViews. So scrolling vertically will always instantiate cells or at least that's what I been seeing.

So my question is, how to optimize the vertical scrolling without the reusable functionality?

The horizontal cells is loaded with a xib and positioned with autolayout. Each cell have at least ten subviews. There is not much blending.

```
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RATableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier];
```

I know its hard to give me advise without more information, but I'm more interested if the situation with no reusing of cells changes any traditional advises about optimizations e.g the use of shouldRasterize or CoreGraphics.

Comment: You should always reuse cells. And cell reuse has nothing to do with the scrolling stuttering. Scrolling stuttering is an animation problem, and is caused by inefficient _drawing_. Use Instruments (CoreAnimation) to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your performance is not adequate, profile to determine what is time consuming in your scenario. Then address the problems present in the profile information.

One of the reasons we have so many ways to accomplish things is that there are many solutions to various problems. Some solutions are better than others for specific tasks we encounter. I could say "10 views - costs a lot!", then you could reduce your view count and find it doesn't make what is presently slow any faster (or just makes your program as fast as it was, but less maintainable/reusable). Another example: `-shouldRasterize` can work for or against you. Depends on what's being drawn.

Even using CoreGraphics, you often have multiple paths you could take in order to get equivalent results. Which is faster depends on a lot of things.

Good optimizations at this point have more to do with understanding your program's (specific) problems/bottlenecks and what makes your program slow, rather than adhering to best practices and the probability that they will address the problems in the program.